# Not able to kill processes that I started using my Go code

Tags: go, unix

I am trying to write a go package that can run a bunch of process and stop/restart them. It is the stop/restart part that is causing the problem for some kind of applications.

I use the https://godoc.org/os/exec library to launch processes. Let's say I launch two process firefox and another process could `curl blog.golang.org` which would keep running.

This is how I launch processes and how I stop them

```
func newWorker(proc *Process) *worker {
    cmd := exec.Command(proc.Executable, proc.Args...)
    cmd.Env = proc.Env
    return &worker{
        status:  "ready",
        command: cmd,
    }
}

func (w *worker) start(crashed chan *worker, completed chan struct{}) {
    w.status = "running"
    err := w.command.Start()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        // signal a crash
        w.status = "crashed"
        crashed <- w
        return
    }
    fmt.Println("ran ", w.command.Path, w.command.Process.Pid)
    completed <- struct{}{}
}

func (w *worker) stop(crashed chan *worker, completed chan struct{}) {
    w.status = "stopped"
    err := w.command.Process.Kill()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("couldn't kill process ", w.command.Path)
    }
    completed <- struct{}{}
}
```

When I run my application to start these process, it launches both the curl command and firefox, but when I try to call the stop method it is kills the processes without any errors but I still see the firefox window open, so I am not sure if the process has exited or not. I tried killing the processes with both `Kill` and `Signal(os.Kill)` both had the same result.

I also tried to change the way I was creating the processes by using `Run` instead of `Start` but in that case while calling the stop method I got these errors

```
os: process already finished  couldn't kill process  /usr/bin/curl
exit status 0  KILLING  /usr/bin/curl
os: process already finished  couldn't kill process  /usr/bin/firefox
```

and the firefox window was still open, I also tried to print out the `ProcessState` field for each command that I was running but it turned out to be `nil`

I am not sure what to do, I want to make sure that my code 100% kills these processes

Comment: The firefox process with the open window is not the process started by the program.  Print the id of the process created the program and compare to the process ids of the running instances of firefox.  I think you will find that the ids are different.

Answer (score 0):

**If you read the [doc](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Process.Kill) for `func (*Process) Kill`**

```golang
func (p *Process) Kill() error
```

> Kill causes the Process to exit immediately. Kill does not wait until
>   the Process has actually exited. This only kills the Process itself,
>   not any other processes it may have started.

So, this might be your case that it doesn't kill any other processes that it may have started.

**Also, this might help**: [Terminating processes in go](https://bigkevmcd.github.io/go/pgrp/context/2019/02/19/terminating-processes-in-go.html)

Comment: > So, this might be your case that it doesn't kill any other processes that it may have started.

but I call stop for each process individually so my concern is not killing the process that that process might have started but only killing that specific process